# How to use ES modules within gulpfile.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

In our project we have `"type": "module"` inside our `package.json` file. Due to this we are unable to use `require` when implementing a `gulpfile.js` file.

Is there a way to use `import` and `export` syntax when defining gulp tasks?